# adding checkbox to a dropdown

Tags: html

`<select><option><input type="checkbox" />Headache</option></select>`

By using the above code i did't get a check box inside a dropdown list.Can you suggest me , how should i proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an input control inside a select element. You'll have to create the drop-down using JavaScript, without using the select element at all.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that didn't work is that form elements don't nest like that.  Fortunately, there's a jquery plugin that can do what you want.  http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/04/jquery-multiselect/

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with "plain" HTML, you'll need to grab JavaScript to progressively enhance a plain dropdown into such a dropdown with help of `<ul><li>` elements and a good shot of CSS. You can find [here](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/) an overview of what's all possible with jQuery (a JavaScript library), such as the [jQuery dropdown checklist](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/).

It's pretty simple, just import the desired JS libraries and apply it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Dropdown with checkboxes.</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#select_id").dropdownchecklist();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="select_id">
            ...
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's all.

Comment: thanks , I have tried it with modification but code is not working ,what should i do? In this code combo box is created without
check box.Please elaborate........

Comment: is there any plugin required for jquery?

Comment: Only JavaScript and every webbrowser supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach on top of BalusC's one is to actually develop your own custom UI element. Unfortunately, this is usually (or always?) browser-specific.

I know you can do that for [Firefox using XUL.](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/9312/0/page/3)

I'm sure you can do some ActiveX tricks for IE though no clue how.

Comment: Sounds like a whole lot of effort for something that be done with some JS and CSS

Comment: For this specific design, possibly. Not always

Answer (score 0):

if we want to perform action on a button along with this checked listbox use javascript and html both.the following code may be helpful to u.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Check box list</title>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function selectCheckBox()
        {
            var total="";
            for(var i=0; i < document.form.languages.length; i++)
            {
                if(document.form.languages[i].checked)
                {
                    total +=document.form.languages[i].value + "\n";
                }
            }
            if(total=="")
            {
                alert("select checkboxes");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Selected Values are : \n"+total);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="CheckBox.jsp">
            <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100px; height: 80px; border: 1px solid #336699; padding-left: 5px">
                <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="English"> English<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Hindi"> Hindi<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Italian"> Italian<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Chinese"> Chinese<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="Japanese"> Japanese<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="German"> German<br>
            </div>

            <br/><input type="button" name="goto" onClick="selectCheckBox()"value="Check">
        </form>
    </body>
```